# How do we merge 2 pages in a pdf file on linux

Tags: linux, shell, pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

I have a pdf file of 10 pages , and I want to merge every two pages of it into a single page , like 1,2->1 : 3,4->2 : and so on ... I learnt about Ghostscript but these are the tools for compressing the .pdf , also there are utilities to merge two or more pdf s together into one,but I unfortunately could not find any to merge pages in the same pdf . Kindly help !

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/).

```
cpdf -twoup in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

Comment: Hey!..yeah this seems promising, but I am clueness on how to run this on Debian Linx , No makefile in their repo provided , also it's just not opening with Wine god know why !!

Comment: plus it's under "a special not-for-commercial-use license" (github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries/blob/master/LICENSE) -- for applications like this that are handled well by open source tools I don't see a point in investing in cpdf - not sure if it has an edge in some special use case though

Answer (score 4):

Installing `pdfjam` adds a command called `pdfjoin` that can be used to join multiple PDF files into one. If your distribution doesn't come with pdfjam, you could also try `pdftk`.

Comment: `pdfjam` also includes `pdfnup`, which is probably more appropriate to the OP's question. `pdfjoin` is for joining multiple PDF files into a single file, not for reducing and combining pages...

Comment: Exacty @twaberg , it's pdfnup that does that!..but essentially what is does is it just merges 2 pages into one,,and i am clueness on adjusting their ratios in that new page . As in, I want to stamp the Even page to the end of its previous page ! such that the stamped page only occupies a smaller chunk of the new formed page

Comment: As of 2023, `pdfnup` seems to have been rolled up into the `pdfjam` binary itself. Now it exists as the `--nup` argument to `pdfjam`.

Answer (score -1):

`pdfunite` is part of the `poppler` package

```
pdfunite 01.pdf 02.pdf 03.pdf out.pdf
```

Comment: No!that is needed if one wants to combine 2 or more pdfs into a single pdf file .

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with pdftk

```
    pdftk test.pdf test1.pdf cat output output.pdf
```